# Why are all classes affected by changes to one class?

Tags: python, class

I have two objects inheriting functionality from a base class. I want to be able to make changes to those classes independently, while sharing functionality from the base class. However, I'm finding that changes to one object affect the other. I've never had this issue before. What is going on here?

Here's an example of how this is set up:

```
#!/bin/python3


class Base(object):
    inputs = []

    def __init__(self, inputs):
        for i in inputs:
            self.inputs.append(i)


class Thing1(Base):

    def __init__(self, inputs):
        super(Thing1, self).__init__(inputs)


class Thing2(Base):

    def __init__(self, inputs):
        super(Thing2, self).__init__(inputs)


t1 = Thing1(["Llama"])
print(t1.inputs)
t2 = Thing2(["Donkey", "Goat"])
print(t2.inputs)
print(t1.inputs)
```

This prints the following:

```
['Llama']
['Llama', 'Donkey', 'Goat']
['Llama', 'Donkey', 'Goat']
```

I want it to print:

```
['Llama']
['Donkey', 'Goat']
['Llama']
```

How do I go from what I am doing to what I want to do? Why are my classes not updating independently?

Edit: Solved. Thanks to Mark Meyer for the solution:

```
class Base(object):

    def __init__(self, inputs):
        self.inputs = []
        for i in inputs:
            self.inputs.append(i)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make `inputs` and instance attribute by defining it in `__init__()`. Otherwise you have a single class attribute that is being shared among the instances.

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, inputs):
        self.inputs = []
        for i in inputs:
            self.inputs.append(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have defined `inputs` as a Class-level member - not an Object level member. These members are shared by all instances of the class. That's why it's getting modified.

```
class X:
    a = ...
```

Here `a` is class-level. Which means it belongs to the class.

```
class X:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = ...
```

Here `a` is object-level. It belongs to the object.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Base(object):
  inputs = []
  ...
```

This declares a class variable `inputs`, similar to a static variable if you're coming from C++ or Java.

```
class Base(object):
  def __init__(...):
    self.inputs = []
    ...
```

This makes it an instance variable. You want it to be created inside your `__init__`, not in the class.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is how you are declaring the `inputs` list.  Declaring it in the class like that (outside of a function) is making that a "static" variable on the class and all classes that extend it.

To fix this, set `self.inputs = []` inside the `__init__` function.

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, inputs):
        self.inputs = []

        for i in inputs:
            self.inputs.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `inputs` belongs to the whole class, not to each object. Change

```
class Base(object):
    inputs = []
```

to

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.inputs = []
```